# JavaScript/JQuery Text Preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking at Google Fonts and I noticed they have a live preview of the text that you can enter up on top.  My question is, how could I go about creating an input field that the user could enter text and see it populate just as Google Fonts does - http://www.google.com/fonts/

I know I would just use keyup to change the text but I am not sure how I actually change the font without creating a ton of .css('font-family...

Let me know your ideas!

Comment: Why not just set the style for the input so that it uses the font you want?

Comment: But I want to have tons of fonts that the user can preview, do you know any apis that are already created?

Comment: @DavidBiga - Have a CSS style defn for each font you need previewed and simply add that class instead of `.css('font-family'...)` - i.e. like how google fonts is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google fonts have `<span>` elements with the appropriate fonts preset.

For ex:

```
<span class="sample Kite-One-normal-400" style="font-size: 28px;">Hello World!</span>
```

All they do when the text is changed is change the content inside the span.

```
$('span.sample').text(<new-text>);
```

Comment: So than by using this how do I make it get the Kite-One.... and change the font?  Just have a JQuery function run through all of the divs to hook the font up for that specified font?

Comment: @DavidBiga - Ok, so if you need to *change* it to use say 'Arial', just do `$('span.sample').addClass('arial-class');` where `<new-font-class> { font-family: arial; }` is where you have your font-family definition.

Comment: so inside the {...} would be, {'font-family', 'Arial'}? Or just simply font-family: Arial;

Comment: The `<new-font-class> { font-family: arial; }` i mentioned is in your CSS file.

Comment: Hmm for some reason I am confused, by chance do you have a JSFiddle example?

Comment: Ohhhh, wait I see so I just create a class for the font in the span and have it defined in a style sheet.

Comment: So why did you have the 'class="sample Kite-One-normal-400"' where it starts with the Kite-One-...?

Comment: @DavidBiga - Exactly. Create a class for each font in your CSS, and simply use that in your JS instead of using `.css('font-family' ...)` from JS.

Comment: @techfootbar I am curious to why you would have the font name with the class?

Comment: In Google fonts, the classes are preset. They don't change the font of a particular preview block. Also, if you inspect their CSS you'll see the definition for `.Kite-One-normal-400`

Comment: So what do you gain by that?

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/dqqDf/

Comment: Oh sweet that helps!  So do you know any quick ways to populate all of the webs normal fonts so I wouldn't have to do each individual?

Comment: Well, you can paste all the font-name one per line in a good text-editor like SublimeText or Notepad++. And then use Regex find-and-replace to transform each line to a CSS class definition.

Comment: Ya, okay thanks man I appreciate all the help!  Your awesome and if you could vote this up because people I guess don't like questions? lol

Answer (score 0):

Google fonts doesn't use a ton of `.css('font-family', val)` and instead have the same number of classes defined for each font family and those classes are being applied to the corresponding span elements.

Comment: Ya that is what I figured.